# Anonymous bean in named Spring @Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

How would I specify an anonymous inner bean in a named Spring Service?

```
@Service("myNamedService")
public class myNamedServiceClass  {

    private InnerBeanType innerBean;

    @Autowired
    public void setInnerBean(InnerBeanType innerBean) {
        this.innerBean = innerBean;
    }

}
```

I'm basically trying to achieve the equivalent of the following Spring XML wiring:

```
<bean name="myNamedService" class="somePackage.myNamedServiceClass">
    <property name="innerBean">
        <bean class="somePackage.InnerBeanType"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent using pure annotations is I think not possible. You can use `@Configuration` though if the purpose is to not expose `innerBean` as a visible bean this way:

```
@Bean
public MyNamedServiceBean myNamedServiceBean(){
  MyNamedServiceClass myNamedServiceBean = new MyNamedServiceClass();
  myNamedServiceBean.setInnerBean(new InnerBeanType());
  return myNamedServiceBean;
}
```